# Cannot Install PIP in a conda enviroment created form a .txt file

Tags: python, pip, conda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Windows subsystem for Linux v2.

We are working on a project and I am trying to create a conda enviroment from a enviroment.txt that a coworker made in her OS system and install all requirements.txt used in pip.

The problem is that I have a lot of conflicts with dependecies and I cannot even install the pip.

So far we've tried on the OSX system:

```
conda env export > environment.yml
```

which theoretically has the conda and pip packages. It gives me the following output:

```
name: MLOps_Project
channels:
  - pytorch
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - absl-py=1.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - aiohttp=3.8.3=py310h90acd4f_1
  - aiosignal=1.3.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - async-timeout=4.0.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - attrs=22.2.0=pyh71513ae_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - blinker=1.5=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - bottleneck=1.3.5=py310h4e76f89_0
  - brotli=1.0.9=hca72f7f_7
  - brotli-bin=1.0.9=hca72f7f_7
  - brotlipy=0.7.0=py310hca72f7f_1002
  - bzip2=1.0.8=h1de35cc_0
  - c-ares=1.18.1=h0d85af4_0
  - ca-certificates=2022.12.7=h033912b_0
  - certifi=2022.12.7=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - cffi=1.15.1=py310h6c40b1e_3
  - charset-normalizer=2.0.4=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - click=8.0.4=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - colorama=0.4.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - contourpy=1.0.5=py310haf03e11_0
  - cryptography=38.0.1=py310hf6deb26_0
  - cycler=0.11.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - ffmpeg=4.3=h0a44026_0
  - flit-core=3.6.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - fonttools=4.25.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - freetype=2.12.1=hd8bbffd_0
  - frozenlist=1.3.3=py310h90acd4f_0
  - fsspec=2022.11.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - gettext=0.21.0=h7535e17_0
  - giflib=5.2.1=haf1e3a3_0
  - gmp=6.2.1=he9d5cce_3
  - gnutls=3.6.15=hed9c0bf_0
  - google-auth-oauthlib=0.4.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - grpcio=1.42.0=py310ha29bfda_0
  - icu=58.2=h0a44026_3
  - idna=3.4=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - importlib-metadata=6.0.0=pyha770c72_0
  - intel-openmp=2021.4.0=hecd8cb5_3538
  - jpeg=9e=hca72f7f_0
  - kiwisolver=1.4.4=py310hcec6c5f_0
  - lame=3.100=h1de35cc_0
  - lcms2=2.12=hf1fd2bf_0
  - lerc=3.0=he9d5cce_0
  - libbrotlicommon=1.0.9=hca72f7f_7
  - libbrotlidec=1.0.9=hca72f7f_7
  - libbrotlienc=1.0.9=hca72f7f_7
  - libcxx=14.0.6=h9765a3e_0
  - libdeflate=1.8=h9ed2024_5
  - libffi=3.4.2=hecd8cb5_6
  - libiconv=1.16=hca72f7f_2
  - libidn2=2.3.2=h9ed2024_0
  - libpng=1.6.37=ha441bb4_0
  - libprotobuf=3.20.1=h8346a28_0
  - libtasn1=4.16.0=h9ed2024_0
  - libtiff=4.4.0=h2cd0358_2
  - libunistring=0.9.10=h9ed2024_0
  - libwebp=1.2.4=h56c3ce4_0
  - libwebp-base=1.2.4=hca72f7f_0
  - libxml2=2.9.14=hbf8cd5e_0
  - lightning-utilities=0.5.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - llvm-openmp=14.0.6=h0dcd299_0
  - lz4-c=1.9.4=hcec6c5f_0
  - markdown=3.4.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - markupsafe=2.1.1=py310h90acd4f_2
  - matplotlib=3.6.2=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - matplotlib-base=3.6.2=py310h220de94_0
  - mkl=2021.4.0=hecd8cb5_637
  - mkl-service=2.4.0=py310hca72f7f_0
  - mkl_fft=1.3.1=py310hf879493_0
  - mkl_random=1.2.2=py310hc081a56_0
  - multidict=6.0.4=py310h90acd4f_0
  - munkres=1.1.4=py_0
  - ncurses=6.3=hca72f7f_3
  - nettle=3.7.3=h230ac6f_1
  - numexpr=2.8.4=py310h9638375_0
  - numpy=1.23.5=py310h9638375_0
  - numpy-base=1.23.5=py310ha98c3c9_0
  - oauthlib=3.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - openh264=2.1.1=h8346a28_0
  - openssl=1.1.1s=hfd90126_1
  - packaging=22.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - pandas=1.5.2=py310h3ea8b11_0
  - pillow=9.3.0=py310h81888ad_1
  - pip=22.3.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - pyasn1=0.4.8=py_0
  - pycparser=2.21=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pyjwt=2.6.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyopenssl=22.0.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pyparsing=3.0.9=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - pysocks=1.7.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - python=3.10.8=h218abb5_1
  - python-dateutil=2.8.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - python-dotenv=0.21.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - python_abi=3.10=2_cp310
  - pytorch=1.13.1=py3.10_0
  - pytorch-lightning=1.8.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pytz=2022.7=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - pyu2f=0.1.5=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyyaml=6.0=py310h90acd4f_5
  - readline=8.2=hca72f7f_0
  - regex=2022.7.9=py310hca72f7f_0
  - requests=2.28.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - requests-oauthlib=1.3.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - rsa=4.9=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - setuptools=65.5.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - six=1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - sqlite=3.40.0=h880c91c_0
  - tensorboard=2.11.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tensorboard-data-server=0.6.1=py310h23bb4e6_4
  - tensorboard-plugin-wit=1.8.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tk=8.6.12=h5d9f67b_0
  - torchaudio=0.13.1=py310_cpu
  - torchmetrics=0.11.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - torchvision=0.14.1=py310_cpu
  - tornado=6.2=py310hca72f7f_0
  - tqdm=4.64.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - typing-extensions=4.4.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - typing_extensions=4.4.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - tzdata=2022g=h04d1e81_0
  - urllib3=1.26.13=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - werkzeug=2.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - wheel=0.37.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - xz=5.2.8=h6c40b1e_0
  - yaml=0.2.5=h0d85af4_2
  - yarl=1.8.2=py310h90acd4f_0
  - zipp=3.11.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - zlib=1.2.13=h4dc903c_0
  - zstd=1.5.2=hcb37349_0
  - pip:
    - aiohttp-retry==2.8.3
    - amqp==5.1.1
    - antlr4-python3-runtime==4.9.3
    - anyio==3.6.2
    - appdirs==1.4.4
    - arrow==1.2.3
    - asyncssh==2.13.0
    - atpublic==3.1.1
    - beautifulsoup4==4.11.1
    - billiard==3.6.4.0
    - blessed==1.19.1
    - cachetools==5.2.1
    - celery==5.2.7
    - click-didyoumean==0.3.0
    - click-plugins==1.1.1
    - click-repl==0.2.0
    - commonmark==0.9.1
    - configobj==5.0.6
    - croniter==1.3.8
    - deepdiff==6.2.3
    - dictdiffer==0.9.0
    - diskcache==5.4.0
    - distro==1.8.0
    - dnspython==2.2.1
    - dpath==2.1.4
    - dulwich==0.20.50
    - dvc==2.41.1
    - dvc-data==0.29.0
    - dvc-gdrive==2.19.1
    - dvc-http==2.30.0
    - dvc-objects==0.14.1
    - dvc-render==0.0.17
    - dvc-studio-client==0.3.0
    - dvc-task==0.1.9
    - dvclive==1.3.2
    - email-validator==1.3.0
    - fastapi==0.89.1
    - filelock==3.9.0
    - flatten-dict==0.4.2
    - flufl-lock==7.1.1
    - funcy==1.17
    - future==0.18.2
    - gitdb==4.0.10
    - gitpython==3.1.30
    - google-api-core==2.11.0
    - google-api-python-client==2.72.0
    - google-auth==2.16.0
    - google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
    - googleapis-common-protos==1.58.0
    - grandalf==0.6
    - h11==0.14.0
    - httpcore==0.16.3
    - httplib2==0.21.0
    - httptools==0.5.0
    - httpx==0.23.3
    - hydra-core==1.3.1
    - inquirer==3.1.2
    - iterative-telemetry==0.0.6
    - itsdangerous==2.1.2
    - jinja2==3.1.2
    - kaggle==1.5.12
    - kombu==5.2.4
    - lightning==1.8.6
    - lightning-cloud==0.5.16
    - nanotime==0.5.2
    - networkx==3.0
    - oauth2client==4.1.3
    - omegaconf==2.3.0
    - ordered-set==4.1.0
    - orjson==3.8.5
    - pathspec==0.9.0
    - prompt-toolkit==3.0.36
    - protobuf==3.20.1
    - psutil==5.9.4
    - pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
    - pydantic==1.10.4
    - pydot==1.4.2
    - pydrive2==1.15.0
    - pygit2==1.11.1
    - pygments==2.14.0
    - pygtrie==2.5.0
    - python-editor==1.0.4
    - python-multipart==0.0.5
    - python-slugify==7.0.0
    - readchar==4.0.3
    - rfc3986==1.5.0
    - rich==13.0.1
    - ruamel-yaml==0.17.21
    - ruamel-yaml-clib==0.2.7
    - scmrepo==0.1.5
    - shortuuid==1.0.11
    - shtab==1.5.8
    - smmap==5.0.0
    - sniffio==1.3.0
    - soupsieve==2.3.2.post1
    - starlette==0.22.0
    - starsessions==1.3.0
    - tabulate==0.9.0
    - tensorboardx==2.5.1
    - text-unidecode==1.3
    - tomlkit==0.11.6
    - traitlets==5.8.1
    - ujson==5.7.0
    - uritemplate==4.1.1
    - uvicorn==0.20.0
    - uvloop==0.17.0
    - vine==5.0.0
    - voluptuous==0.13.1
    - watchfiles==0.18.1
    - wcwidth==0.2.5
    - websocket-client==1.4.2
    - websockets==10.4
    - zc-lockfile==2.0
prefix: /opt/anaconda3/envs/MLOps_Project
```

But when I create the enviroment using:

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - idna==3.4=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - zlib==1.2.13=h4dc903c_0
  - brotlipy==0.7.0=py310hca72f7f_1002
  - libwebp==1.2.4=h56c3ce4_0
  - python-dotenv==0.21.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - kiwisolver==1.4.4=py310hcec6c5f_0
  - tk==8.6.12=h5d9f67b_0
  - requests==2.28.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - lz4-c==1.9.4=hcec6c5f_0
  - mkl_random==1.2.2=py310hc081a56_0
  - yaml==0.2.5=h0d85af4_2
  - mkl-service==2.4.0=py310hca72f7f_0
  - gnutls==3.6.15=hed9c0bf_0
  - frozenlist==1.3.3=py310h90acd4f_0
  - brotli-bin==1.0.9=hca72f7f_7
  - c-ares==1.18.1=h0d85af4_0
  - python==3.10.8=h218abb5_1
  - libdeflate==1.8=h9ed2024_5
  - packaging==22.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - typing_extensions==4.4.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - libxml2==2.9.14=hbf8cd5e_0
  - click==8.0.4=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - brotli==1.0.9=hca72f7f_7
  - pillow==9.3.0=py310h81888ad_1
  - matplotlib==3.6.2=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - giflib==5.2.1=haf1e3a3_0
  - sqlite==3.40.0=h880c91c_0
  - freetype==2.12.1=hd8bbffd_0
  - ffmpeg==4.3=h0a44026_0
  - libbrotlienc==1.0.9=hca72f7f_7
  - libidn2==2.3.2=h9ed2024_0
  - readline==8.2=hca72f7f_0
  - nettle==3.7.3=h230ac6f_1
  - urllib3==1.26.13=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - openh264==2.1.1=h8346a28_0
  - bzip2==1.0.8=h1de35cc_0
  - libcxx==14.0.6=h9765a3e_0
  - cryptography==38.0.1=py310hf6deb26_0
  - setuptools==65.5.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - xz==5.2.8=h6c40b1e_0
  - icu==58.2=h0a44026_3
  - ca-certificates==2022.12.7=h033912b_0
  - libunistring==0.9.10=h9ed2024_0
  - cffi==1.15.1=py310h6c40b1e_3
  - intel-openmp==2021.4.0=hecd8cb5_3538
  - regex==2022.7.9=py310hca72f7f_0
  - libpng==1.6.37=ha441bb4_0
  - contourpy==1.0.5=py310haf03e11_0
  - markupsafe==2.1.1=py310h90acd4f_2
  - lerc==3.0=he9d5cce_0
  - libbrotlicommon==1.0.9=hca72f7f_7
  - libtasn1==4.16.0=h9ed2024_0
  - llvm-openmp==14.0.6=h0dcd299_0
  - bottleneck==1.3.5=py310h4e76f89_0
  - yarl==1.8.2=py310h90acd4f_0
  - openssl==1.1.1s=hfd90126_1
  - libprotobuf==3.20.1=h8346a28_0
  - matplotlib-base==3.6.2=py310h220de94_0
  - numexpr==2.8.4=py310h9638375_0
  - numpy==1.23.5=py310h9638375_0
  - typing-extensions==4.4.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - pandas==1.5.2=py310h3ea8b11_0
  - multidict==6.0.4=py310h90acd4f_0
  - tornado==6.2=py310hca72f7f_0
  - grpcio==1.42.0=py310ha29bfda_0
  - lame==3.100=h1de35cc_0
  - gettext==0.21.0=h7535e17_0
  - libbrotlidec==1.0.9=hca72f7f_7
  - libffi==3.4.2=hecd8cb5_6
  - aiohttp==3.8.3=py310h90acd4f_1
  - libtiff==4.4.0=h2cd0358_2
  - jpeg==9e=hca72f7f_0
  - pip==22.3.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - pytorch==1.13.1=py3.10_0
  - pytz==2022.7=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - libwebp-base==1.2.4=hca72f7f_0
  - lcms2==2.12=hf1fd2bf_0
  - gmp==6.2.1=he9d5cce_3
  - pyparsing==3.0.9=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - pyyaml==6.0=py310h90acd4f_5
  - mkl_fft==1.3.1=py310hf879493_0
  - numpy-base==1.23.5=py310ha98c3c9_0
  - tensorboard-data-server==0.6.1=py310h23bb4e6_4
  - mkl==2021.4.0=hecd8cb5_637
  - zstd==1.5.2=hcb37349_0
  - libiconv==1.16=hca72f7f_2
  - pysocks==1.7.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - ncurses==6.3=hca72f7f_3
```

Then we've tried on the OSX system:

```
conda list --export > conda-requirements.txt
```

Which gives the following output:

```
# This file may be used to create an environment using:
# $ conda create --name <env> --file <this file>
# platform: osx-64
aiohttp=3.8.3=pypi_0
aiohttp-retry=2.8.3=pypi_0
aiosignal=1.3.1=pypi_0
amqp=5.1.1=pypi_0
antlr4-python3-runtime=4.9.3=pypi_0
appdirs=1.4.4=pypi_0
async-timeout=4.0.2=pypi_0
asyncssh=2.13.0=pypi_0
atpublic=3.1.1=pypi_0
attrs=22.2.0=pypi_0
billiard=3.6.4.0=pypi_0
blas=1.0=mkl
bottleneck=1.3.5=py310h4e76f89_0
brotli=1.0.9=hca72f7f_7
brotli-bin=1.0.9=hca72f7f_7
brotlipy=0.7.0=py310hca72f7f_1002
bzip2=1.0.8=h1de35cc_0
ca-certificates=2022.10.11=hecd8cb5_0
cachetools=5.2.1=pypi_0
celery=5.2.7=pypi_0
certifi=2022.12.7=py310hecd8cb5_0
cffi=1.15.1=py310h6c40b1e_3
charset-normalizer=2.0.4=pyhd3eb1b0_0
click=8.0.4=py310hecd8cb5_0
click-didyoumean=0.3.0=pypi_0
click-plugins=1.1.1=pypi_0
click-repl=0.2.0=pypi_0
colorama=0.4.6=pypi_0
commonmark=0.9.1=pypi_0
configobj=5.0.6=pypi_0
contourpy=1.0.5=py310haf03e11_0
cryptography=38.0.1=py310hf6deb26_0
cycler=0.11.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
dictdiffer=0.9.0=pypi_0
diskcache=5.4.0=pypi_0
distro=1.8.0=pypi_0
dpath=2.1.4=pypi_0
dulwich=0.20.50=pypi_0
dvc=2.41.1=pypi_0
dvc-data=0.29.0=pypi_0
dvc-gdrive=2.19.1=pypi_0
dvc-http=2.30.0=pypi_0
dvc-objects=0.14.1=pypi_0
dvc-render=0.0.17=pypi_0
dvc-studio-client=0.3.0=pypi_0
dvc-task=0.1.9=pypi_0
dvclive=1.3.2=pypi_0
ffmpeg=4.3=h0a44026_0
filelock=3.9.0=pypi_0
flatten-dict=0.4.2=pypi_0
flit-core=3.6.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
flufl-lock=7.1.1=pypi_0
fonttools=4.25.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
freetype=2.12.1=hd8bbffd_0
frozenlist=1.3.3=pypi_0
fsspec=2022.11.0=pypi_0
funcy=1.17=pypi_0
future=0.18.2=pypi_0
gettext=0.21.0=h7535e17_0
giflib=5.2.1=haf1e3a3_0
gitdb=4.0.10=pypi_0
gitpython=3.1.30=pypi_0
gmp=6.2.1=he9d5cce_3
gnutls=3.6.15=hed9c0bf_0
google-api-core=2.11.0=pypi_0
google-api-python-client=2.72.0=pypi_0
google-auth=2.16.0=pypi_0
google-auth-httplib2=0.1.0=pypi_0
googleapis-common-protos=1.58.0=pypi_0
grandalf=0.6=pypi_0
httplib2=0.21.0=pypi_0
hydra-core=1.3.1=pypi_0
icu=58.2=h0a44026_3
idna=3.4=py310hecd8cb5_0
intel-openmp=2021.4.0=hecd8cb5_3538
iterative-telemetry=0.0.6=pypi_0
jpeg=9e=hca72f7f_0
kaggle=1.5.12=pypi_0
kiwisolver=1.4.4=py310hcec6c5f_0
kombu=5.2.4=pypi_0
lame=3.100=h1de35cc_0
lcms2=2.12=hf1fd2bf_0
lerc=3.0=he9d5cce_0
libbrotlicommon=1.0.9=hca72f7f_7
libbrotlidec=1.0.9=hca72f7f_7
libbrotlienc=1.0.9=hca72f7f_7
libcxx=14.0.6=h9765a3e_0
libdeflate=1.8=h9ed2024_5
libffi=3.4.2=hecd8cb5_6
libiconv=1.16=hca72f7f_2
libidn2=2.3.2=h9ed2024_0
libpng=1.6.37=ha441bb4_0
libtasn1=4.16.0=h9ed2024_0
libtiff=4.4.0=h2cd0358_2
libunistring=0.9.10=h9ed2024_0
libwebp=1.2.4=h56c3ce4_0
libwebp-base=1.2.4=hca72f7f_0
libxml2=2.9.14=hbf8cd5e_0
llvm-openmp=14.0.6=h0dcd299_0
lz4-c=1.9.4=hcec6c5f_0
matplotlib=3.6.2=py310hecd8cb5_0
matplotlib-base=3.6.2=py310h220de94_0
mkl=2021.4.0=hecd8cb5_637
mkl-service=2.4.0=py310hca72f7f_0
mkl_fft=1.3.1=py310hf879493_0
mkl_random=1.2.2=py310hc081a56_0
multidict=6.0.4=pypi_0
munkres=1.1.4=py_0
nanotime=0.5.2=pypi_0
ncurses=6.3=hca72f7f_3
nettle=3.7.3=h230ac6f_1
networkx=3.0=pypi_0
numexpr=2.8.4=py310h9638375_0
numpy=1.23.5=py310h9638375_0
numpy-base=1.23.5=py310ha98c3c9_0
oauth2client=4.1.3=pypi_0
omegaconf=2.3.0=pypi_0
openh264=2.1.1=h8346a28_0
openssl=1.1.1s=hca72f7f_0
packaging=22.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
pandas=1.5.2=py310h3ea8b11_0
pathspec=0.9.0=pypi_0
pillow=9.3.0=py310h81888ad_1
pip=22.3.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
prompt-toolkit=3.0.36=pypi_0
protobuf=4.21.12=pypi_0
psutil=5.9.4=pypi_0
pyasn1=0.4.8=pypi_0
pyasn1-modules=0.2.8=pypi_0
pycparser=2.21=pyhd3eb1b0_0
pydot=1.4.2=pypi_0
pydrive2=1.15.0=pypi_0
pygit2=1.11.1=pypi_0
pygments=2.14.0=pypi_0
pygtrie=2.5.0=pypi_0
pyopenssl=22.0.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyparsing=3.0.9=py310hecd8cb5_0
pysocks=1.7.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
python=3.10.8=h218abb5_1
python-dateutil=2.8.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-dotenv=0.21.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
python-slugify=7.0.0=pypi_0
pytorch=1.13.1=py3.10_0
pytz=2022.7=py310hecd8cb5_0
pyyaml=6.0=pypi_0
readline=8.2=hca72f7f_0
regex=2022.7.9=py310hca72f7f_0
requests=2.28.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
rich=13.0.1=pypi_0
rsa=4.9=pypi_0
ruamel-yaml=0.17.21=pypi_0
ruamel-yaml-clib=0.2.7=pypi_0
scmrepo=0.1.5=pypi_0
setuptools=65.5.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
shortuuid=1.0.11=pypi_0
shtab=1.5.8=pypi_0
six=1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
smmap=5.0.0=pypi_0
sqlite=3.40.0=h880c91c_0
tabulate=0.9.0=pypi_0
text-unidecode=1.3=pypi_0
tk=8.6.12=h5d9f67b_0
tomlkit=0.11.6=pypi_0
torchaudio=0.13.1=py310_cpu
torchvision=0.14.1=py310_cpu
tornado=6.2=py310hca72f7f_0
tqdm=4.64.1=pypi_0
typing_extensions=4.4.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
tzdata=2022g=h04d1e81_0
uritemplate=4.1.1=pypi_0
urllib3=1.26.13=py310hecd8cb5_0
vine=5.0.0=pypi_0
voluptuous=0.13.1=pypi_0
wcwidth=0.2.5=pypi_0
wheel=0.37.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
xz=5.2.8=h6c40b1e_0
yarl=1.8.2=pypi_0
zc-lockfile=2.0=pypi_0
zlib=1.2.13=h4dc903c_0
zstd=1.5.2=hcb37349_0
```

Then to get the packages from pip:

```
 pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Which gives the following output:

```
aiohttp==3.8.3
aiohttp-retry==2.8.3
aiosignal==1.3.1
amqp==5.1.1
antlr4-python3-runtime==4.9.3
appdirs==1.4.4
async-timeout==4.0.2
asyncssh==2.13.0
atpublic==3.1.1
attrs==22.2.0
billiard==3.6.4.0
Bottleneck @ file:///private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_29949159-f86f-474b-bc1f-aaa1e0e222b4ofusifik/croots/recipe/bottleneck_1657175564045/work
brotlipy==0.7.0
cachetools==5.2.1
celery==5.2.7
certifi @ file:///private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_477u68wvzm/croot/certifi_1671487773341/work/certifi
cffi @ file:///private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_1b0qzba5nr/croot/cffi_1670423213150/work
charset-normalizer @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/charset-normalizer_1630003229654/work
click @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/2d66025a-4d79-47c4-43be-6220928b6c82/volume/click_1646056610594/work
click-didyoumean==0.3.0
click-plugins==1.1.1
click-repl==0.2.0
colorama==0.4.6
commonmark==0.9.1
configobj==5.0.6
contourpy @ file:///private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_17gskqgptz/croots/recipe/contourpy_1663827415320/work
cryptography @ file:///private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_3evwafgyg8/croot/cryptography_1665612651044/work
cycler @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/cycler_1637851556182/work
dictdiffer==0.9.0
diskcache==5.4.0
distro==1.8.0
dpath==2.1.4
dulwich==0.20.50
dvc==2.41.1
dvc-data==0.29.0
dvc-gdrive==2.19.1
dvc-http==2.30.0
dvc-objects==0.14.1
dvc-render==0.0.17
dvc-studio-client==0.3.0
dvc-task==0.1.9
dvclive==1.3.2
filelock==3.9.0
flatten-dict==0.4.2
flit_core @ file:///opt/conda/conda-bld/flit-core_1644941570762/work/source/flit_core
flufl.lock==7.1.1
fonttools==4.25.0
frozenlist==1.3.3
fsspec==2022.11.0
funcy==1.17
future==0.18.2
gitdb==4.0.10
GitPython==3.1.30
google-api-core==2.11.0
google-api-python-client==2.72.0
google-auth==2.16.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.58.0
grandalf==0.6
httplib2==0.21.0
hydra-core==1.3.1
idna @ file:///private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_00jf0h4zbt/croot/idna_1666125573348/work
iterative-telemetry==0.0.6
kaggle==1.5.12
kiwisolver @ file:///private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_e26jwrjf6j/croot/kiwisolver_1672387151391/work
kombu==5.2.4
matplotlib @ file:///private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_35aw7vfp_z/croot/matplotlib-suite_1670466139477/work
mkl-fft==1.3.1
mkl-random @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/a9eca864-069c-4240-73c8-4e51b036a10d/volume/mkl_random_1639994047876/work
mkl-service==2.4.0
multidict==6.0.4
munkres==1.1.4
nanotime==0.5.2
networkx==3.0
numexpr @ file:///private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_cef3ah6r8w/croot/numexpr_1668713880672/work
numpy @ file:///private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_8cgikbzvtd/croot/numpy_and_numpy_base_1672336184666/work
oauth2client==4.1.3
omegaconf==2.3.0
packaging @ file:///private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_bet5qdixgt/croot/packaging_1671697440883/work
pandas==1.5.2
pathspec==0.9.0
Pillow==9.3.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.36
protobuf==4.21.12
psutil==5.9.4
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pycparser_1636541352034/work
pydot==1.4.2
PyDrive2==1.15.0
pygit2==1.11.1
Pygments==2.14.0
pygtrie==2.5.0
pyOpenSSL @ file:///opt/conda/conda-bld/pyopenssl_1643788558760/work
pyparsing @ file:///private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_3a17y2delq/croots/recipe/pyparsing_1661452538853/work
PySocks @ file:///Users/builder/ci_310/pysocks_1642536366386/work
python-dateutil @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/python-dateutil_1626374649649/work
python-dotenv @ file:///private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_ebulf7sz20/croot/python-dotenv_1669132564141/work
python-slugify==7.0.0
pytz @ file:///private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_ddzpsmm2_f/croot/pytz_1671697430473/work
PyYAML==6.0
regex @ file:///private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_978efa21-43f5-4f43-9f25-acd8393817ddce2xcjaf/croots/recipe/regex_1658257186496/work
requests @ file:///private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_516b78ce-034d-4395-b9b5-1d78c2847384qtnol99l/croots/recipe/requests_1657734628886/work
rich==13.0.1
rsa==4.9
ruamel.yaml==0.17.21
ruamel.yaml.clib==0.2.7
scmrepo==0.1.5
shortuuid==1.0.11
shtab==1.5.8
six @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/six_1644875935023/work
smmap==5.0.0
tabulate==0.9.0
text-unidecode==1.3
tomlkit==0.11.6
torch==1.13.1
torchaudio==0.13.1
torchvision==0.14.1
tornado @ file:///private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_1fimz6o0gc/croots/recipe/tornado_1662061695695/work
tqdm==4.64.1
typing_extensions @ file:///private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_4b7xacf029/croot/typing_extensions_1669923792404/work
uritemplate==4.1.1
urllib3 @ file:///private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_ffvqcdv424/croot/urllib3_1670526991804/work
vine==5.0.0
voluptuous==0.13.1
wcwidth==0.2.5
yarl==1.8.2
zc.lockfile==2.0
```

With this two requirements files I've tried to create the enviroment with conda, which creates the env successfully. But when I try to intall pip in the enviroment, it gives me the following error: (I will only copy part of the output as it gives me conflicts with each package)

```
Package futures conflicts for:
conda-forge/noarch::tensorboard==2.11.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0 -> grpcio[version='>=1.24.3'] -> futures[version='>=2.2.0']
defaults/osx-64::matplotlib==3.6.2=py310hecd8cb5_0 -> tornado[version='>=5'] -> futures

Package libbrotlienc conflicts for:
defaults/osx-64::brotli-bin==1.0.9=hca72f7f_7 -> libbrotlienc==1.0.9=hca72f7f_7
defaults/osx-64::brotli==1.0.9=hca72f7f_7 -> libbrotlienc==1.0.9=hca72f7f_7
defaults/noarch::fonttools==4.25.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> brotli[version='>=1.0.1'] -> libbrotlienc==1.0.9[build='hca72f7f_7|h5eee18b_7']

Package llvm-openmp conflicts for:
defaults/osx-64::gettext==0.21.0=h7535e17_0 -> llvm-openmp[version='>=10.0.0']
defaults/osx-64::gnutls==3.6.15=hed9c0bf_0 -> gettext[version='>=0.19.8.1'] -> llvm-openmp[version='>=10.0.0']

Package tensorboard-plugin-wit conflicts for:
conda-forge/noarch::pytorch-lightning==1.8.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0 -> tensorboard[version='>=2.9.1'] -> tensorboard-plugin-wit[version='>=1.6.0']
conda-forge/noarch::tensorboard==2.11.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0 -> tensorboard-plugin-wit[version='>=1.6.0']

Package fonttools conflicts for:
defaults/osx-64::matplotlib==3.6.2=py310hecd8cb5_0 -> matplotlib-base[version='>=3.6.2,<3.6.3.0a0'] -> fonttools[version='>=4.22.0']
defaults/osx-64::matplotlib-base==3.6.2=py310h220de94_0 -> fonttools[version='>=4.22.0']

Package kiwisolver conflicts for:
defaults/osx-64::matplotlib==3.6.2=py310hecd8cb5_0 -> matplotlib-base[version='>=3.6.2,<3.6.3.0a0'] -> kiwisolver[version='>=1.0.1']
defaults/osx-64::matplotlib-base==3.6.2=py310h220de94_0 -> kiwisolver[version='>=1.0.1']

Package aiohttp conflicts for:
conda-forge/noarch::google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0 -> google-auth[version='>=1.0.0'] -> aiohttp[version='>=3.6.2,<4.0.0dev']
conda-forge/noarch::google-auth==2.15.0=pyh1a96a4e_0 -> aiohttp[version='>=3.6.2,<4.0.0dev']
conda-forge/noarch::tensorboard==2.11.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0 -> google-auth[version='>=1.6.3,<3'] -> aiohttp[version='>=3.6.2,<4.0.0dev']The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.35=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.35=0
  - conda-forge/noarch::tensorboard==2.11.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0 -> grpcio[version='>=1.24.3'] -> __osx[version='>=10.10']
  - defaults/osx-64::grpcio==1.42.0=py310ha29bfda_0 -> __osx[version='>=10.10']
  - defaults/osx-64::matplotlib-base==3.6.2=py310h220de94_0 -> __osx[version='>=10.11']
  - defaults/osx-64::matplotlib==3.6.2=py310hecd8cb5_0 -> matplotlib-base[version='>=3.6.2,<3.6.3.0a0'] -> __osx[version='>=10.11']
  - openssl -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']

Your installed version is: 2.35
```

I have no clue how to fix the problem.

If you can give a hand I'll apreciate it. If you need any extra specs, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Please replace images with formatted code blocks

Comment: See duplicate. `conda list` is inappropriate for cross-platform. And for PyPI packages, one needs to use `pip list --freeze` to properly identify git-installed and editable packages.